# How to use existing curtain rod bracket with a flat hook

Tags: curtain-rail

My wife and I moved into a house built in 1954 (in Orlando, FL) and found these brackets above some windows. When the house was staged, they had curtains hanging from them, but we can't figure out what type of rod would work on these. These are mounted into masonry so we'd prefer to not remove it and install new ones, if possible. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image: One side of the bracket]

[image: Second side of the bracket]

Comment: Anything screwed into masonry with a wall plug is the easiest thing to remove. You can easily take them out without damaging the wall, easily fill the hole, and easily drill another hole. If it was drywall, I'd be much more worried about removing it, because doing *anything* to drywall normally breaks it.

Comment: Clarifying point since neither answer mentions it. Those are for a "valance" rod. I would not call them "curtain" rods. Most curtains would not work well on them from both a weight perspective, and the fact that the rods are not strongly affixed to the bracket.

Answer (score 16):

These lightweight metal U-shaped curtain rods engage those hooks. The uprights of the U are maybe 3" or 4" long and the base is straight and whatever is needed to span the window. The rod is pushed on while angled upward then pulled horizontal. There is a hole in the upper aspect of the rod which the top hook protrudes through. The curtain rod is in two parts one of which slips inside the other to allow width adjustment.

You *might* have to scrape paint off the hooks for them to properly engage. Depending on the span of the widow these rods may need one (or more) supports in the middle. The usual supports are metal hooks which screw into the header above the window. Usually these come in the parts package accompanying the rod.

[image: curtain rod]

Answer (score 10):

The good news is that this is a mount for one of the cheapest curtain rods available. The bad news is the same. Here's [an example of the general type](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-2-Clearance-White-Basic-Adjustable-Curtain-Rod-28-46/50015118), not an endorsement.

By and large they're interchangeable, but you may need to pay some attention to the height of the internal channel (must be at least sufficient to fit around the protruding part of your bracket) and the distance between the wall-end and the hole that the protruding "horn" will hook into. Since these are low-end commodity products and come with their own mounting hooks included, these specs may not be listed online and you'll have to measure in the shop-- or just take your chances, as again these are frequently interchangeable and generally inexpensive.